# Why is the class attribute being modified?

Tags: python, class

In my book it says

> Use class attributes to define properties that should have the same value for every class instance. Use instance attributes for properties that vary from one instance to another.

But then, in an example, the `species` class attribute is modified for `miles` as shown below:

```
class Dog:
    species = "Canis familiaris"
   
miles = Dog()
snoopy = Dog()
miles.species = "Felis silvestris"
```

That means that the `species` class attribute is not for the entire `Dog` class. Have I misunderstood something or is it simply normal to customise class attributes?

Comment: What you can do is print `Dog.species`, `miles.species` and `snoopy.species`. @mkrieger1 has already explained what you'll find, but this might be helpful for your understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the class attribute being modified?

It isn't. `miles` is an instance of the `Dog` class, so assigning to `miles.species` creates an instance attribute.

> That means that the `species` class attribute is not for the entire Dog class.

In the code you have shown, there are two things called `species`.

- An attribute of the class `Dog` (`"Canis familiaris"`), which is unchanged for the whole program.
- An attribute of the instance `miles` (`"Felis silvestris"`), which only applies to `miles`, but not to the whole `Dog` class, nor to the `snoopy` instance.

Since `snoopy` doesn't have its own `species` instance attribute, accessing `snoopy.species` will fall back to `Dog.species`.

Answer (score 3):

Your book's summary of the idea is correct but I can see that it may be vague to a new OOP learner.

Proper practice dictates that class attributes be defined as such:

```
class Dog:
    species = "Canis familiaris"
    # ... other methods, etc.
```

but instance attributes are meant to be *individual to each object you create from the class*. When defining a class properly, you would also want to include an initialization method to be executed on object creation. i.e.:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, species):
        self.species = "Canis familiaris"  # This is an instance attribute
```

To differentiate between a class attribute and an instance attribute, they are referred to differently: (See Sumant's answer for a good rundown)

```
# class Dog: ...
miles = Dog()
print(Dog.species)  # This prints the class attribute
print(miles.species)  # This prints the instance attribute (if found)
```

It is a confusing concept but I hope that this answer clarifies it at least a little.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
class Dog:
    species = "Canis familiaris"
   
miles = Dog()
snoopy = Dog()
miles.species = "Felis silvestris"

print(miles.species)
print(snoopy.species)
print(Dog.species)
```

Output:

```
'Felis silvestris'
'Canis familiaris'
'Canis familiaris'
```

You could take this a step further and do:

```
class Dog:
    species = "Canis familiaris"

miles = Dog()
snoopy = Dog()
miles.species = "Felis silvestris"

scooby = Dog()
print(scooby.species)
```

Output:

```
'Canis familiaris'
```